# Redirect response to download file

Tags: c#, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a generic handler that I call using this very basic js code:

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("fileId", this.model.get("id"));

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '/genericHandlers/DownloadFile.ashx');

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // Do something here?
        }
    }

    xhr.send(formData);
```

My generic handler code seems to look ok to me. Basically I'm attempting to build the response header and I thought that when this handler returned it would begin the download of the file.

**Handler code:**

```
   var fileId = context.Request.Form["fileId"];

   // File stored in the db as a byte array

   var file = (from f in dataContext.OneEVA_Docs_File_Storages
          where Equals(f.ID, fileId)
          select f).FirstOrDefault();

   context.Response.Clear();

   context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", file.ContentType);
   context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.ContentLength.ToString());

   context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}; size={1}", file.Name, file.ContentLength));

   context.Response.BinaryWrite(file.File_Image.ToArray());
   context.Response.Flush();

   context.Response.End();
```

The `XHR` request completes ok. Here is the response header I get back:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=Mikes File; size=1860113
Content-Length:1860113
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Wed, 16 May 2012 14:08:01 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? Does the file not get put into the response?

Comment: @sinni800 It just comes back, no download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't start a download in the browser. It's difficult to achieve using a POST request. Can it not be a GET request if you are only passing an id? Then you just do

```
document.location.href = '/genericHandlers/DownloadFile.ashx?id=' + this.model.get("id");
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. Can you see any downside to using a `GET` rather than a `POST` in this situation?

Comment: I guess the downside is that I couldnt do any error handling, like if for example the file didnt exist.

Comment: @MikeFielden You can - if the file doesn't exist, just serve up an error page or redirect instead of serving the download. Of course, that means leaving the page. Maybe check your file exists before you give your users the link to click on.