# What is equivalent to the following inside a successful XHR request?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I posted a question about a less specific topic earlier, located here: [Redirect response to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620969/redirect-response-to-download-file)

You can read the details there if you'd like.

Tim gave me a good answer to just set the `document.location.href = '/genericHandlers/DownloadFile.ashx?id=' + this.model.get("id");` and just use a `GET` rather than the `POST` I originally thought.

The only problem with this approach is that I cant gracefully fail if the file isnt found. 
So my question now is:

What, inside the `XHR` object, is equilvent to Tim's answer? Basically, all I want to do is begin the download. Ive tried:

`document.location.href = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();`

But that obviously doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can first make an AJAX request to see if the page will return a 404 error or not. This creates performance and bandwidth issues though.

This question has answers with the implantation details: [How can I check existence of a file with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657121/how-can-i-check-existence-of-a-file-with-javascript)

Comment: My file is stored in a database as a byte[], so I have to query for it. If it exists there isnt a problem handling it that way, if it doesnt there lies the problem. I could pass back an empty response header but then the will obviously redirect to that page.